# Active Directory group add to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory

I would like to add an Active Directory Group to the SQL Server, so that I do not have to provide windows authentication o the server to every user. Is this possible?

Another thing is how do I enable my .NET application to connect to the database using this Active Directory credential?

Thanks in advance
 Nishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your questions can be answered by searching!

- Adding AD group to SQL server logins is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server)
- Connection strings to SQL server with Windows Auth is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359579/classic-asp-sql-server-2008-connection-string-using-windows-authentication)

Comment: I am able to add the AD group, but unable to login from my application based on this AD group. The connection string I am using is Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=TestDatabase;server=TestServer;Connect Timeout=60

Comment: You asked for "Login" originally, but I'm guessing you mean you need database users too - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134319/difference-between-a-user-and-a-login-in-sql-server) for an explanation

Comment: Thanks Bridge. I should not be an user in the database. Not even disabled. Only then the active directory group will considered.